# DOXYGEN : Missing navigation tree in index.html and other pages

Tags: treeview, doxygen

I'm using the version 1.8.3.1 of Doxygen for a project. As you know, if you put the `GENERATE_TREEVIEW` tag to `YES` you obtain a left frame with a "navigation tree" with the related modules, links to the methods...

I don't know why but this left-hand frame disappear sometimes (for Firefox, Chrome is working good), It's just blank

I try to find a solution but I see lot of questions without answer.

Did anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: You write you are using "version 1.8.3.1 of Doxygen", this version is quite old, what happens with the current version (1.8.13)?

Comment: It's worse... with this version there is not even the left-hand frame and the modules index at the top and I don't know why

Comment: Please create a small example signaling this problem and specify also the browsers in which you see the problems (including their version numbers and the platform you are using). When necessary file a bug report in bugzilla.